# Updating with multiple ids

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update multiple ids with :

```
 public function rec(Request $request){
    $where = $request->all();
    $update = ['recieve' => '1'];
    DB::table('trainee')->whereIn('id',$where)->update($update);
    return response()->json($where['ids']);
}
```

inside $where is

```
(2) ["6", "3"]0: "6"1: "3"length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

but only id = 6 is updated

how can i update all ids inside the $where variable?

Comment: Try to change string array into integer array like this [6, 3]

Comment: or try DB::table('trainee')->whereIn('id',$where['ids'])->update($update);